# Download Files from a Website with Python

Tags: python, web, download

I have about 300 small files that I need to download from a website. All are located in one directory. The files are of different sizes and have different extensions. I don't want to type each one into my web browser and then click 'save as' and such. I want to give my list to python and have it download and save each file in a directory. If python can simply download the directory, that would be even better.

Comment: If this is all what you need, use wget or curl. If you really want a Python solution (like: you're not on Unix), you can use a package like this one: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget

Comment: Probably easier to just use [`wget`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) with the `--recursive` option.

Comment: Go to the website with chrome and do `right-click + save as` . You will get a folder with all the files on the site along with its html

Comment: @ytpillai lol such a bad solution. That would never work with a GDB.

Comment: And he said that he specifically did not want to do that......wow I'm an idiot

Comment: I found an answer on the internet but I can't write it in the comments, please ask another question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python).  I would favor using Requests as it's generally great, but urllib2 is in the standard library so doesn't require the installation of a new package.

Comment: I don't think he wants a programming solution

Comment: On second thoughts, if you're saving the files, urlretrieve in urllib is probably easier.

Comment: @doukremt: he asked a question specifically about Python on a programming Q&A site. Why would you assume he doesn't want to program?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on python 3.3, you're looking for urllib:

```
import urllib.request
url = r"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png"
opener = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
file_out = open("my_image.png", "wb")
file_out.write(opener.readall())
file_out.close()
```

You should now have a file in your working directory called "my_image.png"